Wordpress SMTP plugins causing issues with admin-ajax.php
I have a Wordpress website recently migrated to new dedicated hosting. I can't make any SMTP plugin work: no matter which one I try, my admin-ajax.php keeps loading and loading... this is causing also my website to stop working (all the forms just won't submit).
I have contacted my hosting company and they can't see any issue in there. Upon checking, I found this error: "AH01630: client denied by server configuration: [MYPATH]/index.php, referer: http://[MYWEBSITE]". Strangely, the "referee" is a HTTP URL, but my website is in HTTPS.
I believe it's a CORS error, but I can't really make it work.
I have tried WP Mail SMTP, FluentSMTP and others and still no luck. A plugin I have tried once didn't cause the error in question, but was returning a "can't connect to the host" generic message.
Any help you can give me, will be much appreciated.

have you tried an ssl plugin like "really simple ssl"? install and configure it and see if the error persists.

Is this a programming question? If yes, please [edit] and include a [mcve]. If this is about wordpress configuration, it's off-topic here. Try [wordpress.se] but check their help pages first, so that you can add more relevant details like configuration files and how exactly you trigger the error.

Thank you Mohammad. I have tried but the issue still persists unfortunately.
Robert, thank you for pointing me to the right direction
